# Обработака WM_NCHITTEST сообщения

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, компоненты

Есть две панели. Панель B вложена в панель A. Как перенаправить WM_NCHITTEST от B так, что бы панель владелец А обрабатывала это сообщение. Предполагается сделать панель В как сплиттер. Т.е при наведении на неё курсора мыши появлялся курсор как при изменении размера и можно было изменять размер панели А. Использую Delphi 7

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот обработчик для А

```
procedure TPanelEx.WMNCHitTest(var Msg: TWMNCHitTest);
var
  zScreenPt: TPoint;
  zOwnerPt: TPoint;
begin
  inherited;
  if not (csDesigning in  ComponentState) then
  begin
    if not Assigned(Parent) then Exit;
    zScreenPt := ScreenToClient(Point(Msg.Xpos, Msg.Ypos));
    zOwnerPt :=  TControl(Parent).ScreenToClient(Point(Msg.Xpos, Msg.Ypos));
    if (zScreenPt.y >= Height - BevelWidth) and (zOwnerPt.y < TControl(Parent).Height - BevelWidth - 1) then
      Msg.Result := HTBOTTOM
   end;
end;
```

Панель B создается вот так

```
constructor TPanelEx.Create(aOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FShiftingPanel := nil;
  OnCanResize := OnCanPanelResize;
  BevelWidth := 2;
  Ctl3D := false;
  FPrevPanel := nil;
  FBottomPanel := TsPanel.Create(Self);
  FBottomPanel.Parent := Self;
  FBottomPanel.Height := 16;
  FBottomPanel.Align := alBottom;
  FBottomPanel.OnMouseEnter := OnMouseEnter;
  FBottomPanel.OnMouseLeave := OnMouseLeave;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В соответствии с [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), если необходимо "пропустить" `WM_NCHitTest` в родительское окно, необходимо вернуть `HTTRANSPARENT`.

Таким образом, `BottomPanel` также должен заполучить свой обработчик (пример выполнен на основе стандартных `TPanel`, для работы с `TsPanel` измените тип родителя. Упрощен, обработку `csDesigning` вы можете добавить сами):

```pascal
type
  TSizeBoxPanel = class(TPanel)
  private
    procedure WMNCHHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitMessage); message WM_NCHITTEST;
  end;

  TSizedPanel = class(TPanel)
  private
    FSizeBoxPanel: TSizeBoxPanel;
    procedure WMNCHHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitMessage); message WM_NCHITTEST;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

{ TSizedPanel }

procedure TSizeBoxPanel.WMNCHHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitMessage);
begin
  // если панель, которую считаем "сплиттером" приняла сообщение,
  // значит курсор находится где-то над ней. Просто пропускаем сообщение выше.
  Message.Result := HTTRANSPARENT;
end;

{ TSizedPanel }

constructor TSizedPanel.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FSizeBoxPanel:=TSizeBoxPanel.Create(nil);
  FSizeBoxPanel.Parent:=Self;
  FSizeBoxPanel.Align:=alBottom;
  FSizeBoxPanel.Height:=20;
end;

procedure TSizedPanel.WMNCHHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitMessage);
var
  p: TPoint;
begin
  p:=ScreenToClient(Point(Message.XCursor, Message.YCursor));
  // если курсор находится над сплиттером - возвращаем нужное значение.
  if ControlAtPos(p, True, True) = FSizeBoxPanel then
    Message.Result := HTBOTTOM;
end;
```

Пример использования:

```pascal
TForm9 = class(TForm)
  procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
private
  { Private declarations }
  FPanel: TSizedPanel;
public
  { Public declarations }
end;

procedure TForm9.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FPanel:=TSizedPanel.Create(nil);
  FPanel.Parent:=Self;
  FPanel.Left:=10;
  FPanel.Top:=10;
end;
```

Comment: @gregor, к сожалению, не обладаю установленной D7, поэтому часть кода может отличаться наименованиями. Как минимум - в вашем коде используется `Msg.Xpos`, а в последних версиях Delphi - `Msg.XCursor`. Надеюсь, это не будет большим препятствием.